# Using PostgreSQL MD5 hash to calculate a 64 bit hash value for advisory lock functions?

Tags: algorithms, hashing, postgres

I have a particular problem addressing the PostgreSQL advisory locking functions using the `bigint` variants.

Basically I want to create a 64 bit `bigint` value from a `text` type obtained with the PostgreSQL `md5()` function from an arbitrary `text_input_context` input.

The idea is to emulate / simulate a *table row lock behavior<sup>1</sup>*, where the text context is build from the full table name (schema + table name), and the table's keyfield values for a particularly selected row.
It might be acceptable in our application to lock even more rows due to collisions of these hash values, but ensuring to at least have that row is protected for updates from other sessions.
The lock / unlock would be ever straightforward and sequential to protect concurrent accesses of a specific table by design.

Originally the `md5()` function returns a 128 bit value represented as a hexadecimal text value of 32 bytes.

I want to convert this to a `bigint` value, which I can use with the [PostgreSQL advisory lock functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADVISORY-LOCKS).

When doing [some research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375369/convert-hex-string-to-bigint-in-postgres) I found a way to just cut the 128 bit value output of the `md5()` function for it's 1st 16 bytes, and convert these to a 64 bit `bigint` value that can be passed to the PostgreSQL advisory lock functions<sup>2</sup>:

```
SELECT pg_catalog.pg_advisory_lock(('x' || 
             pg_catalog.left(pg_catalog.md5(text_input_context),16)::bit(64)::bigint)
```

I am well aware that using the `md5()` algorithm already looses information regarding the `text_input_context`, though I want to reduce that to a minimum, and even more when just using the 1st 16 bytes of the md5 hash value.

**My question is:**
Is that just a too naive approach, or can we have better implementations to compute a 64 bit value from a 128 bit hash value?

When researching I found the idea to additionally xor-ing the lower 16 byte part with the upper 16 byte part. But wouldn't that be even worse by means of distribution?

---

Regarding some comments advising to use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, `SELECT FOR UPDATE NOWAIT` or `SELECT FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED`, please note that this won't help to solve my specific problem.

1. The `SELECT` commands are done internally by some DB access component, where I have little to no chance to change the behavior how the component issues these statements against the database.
2. What I need is to indicate that a particular table row is locked in the GUI, but still show all the information in the form.

---

PS.: May be this question better applies to [SE Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions), but in the end it's more about the algorithmic approach IMO.

PPS.: In case that matters anyhow, the applications are written in Delphi, using the Devart UniDAC components.

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>The problem occurs in the context, where we try to replace an ISAM (flat file) database system (ADS) with PostgreSQL. The row locking in the original system is implicit, when an application process (session) holds a cursor to a table row for updating.</sub>

<sup>2)</sup><sub>Of course the text context value would be passed as a prepared query parameter, so I am aware about the dangers of SQL-injection, or other unexpected syntax issues.</sub>

Comment: Also I am pretty sure that asking at SE Code Review would complain about lacking context, thus I decided to ask here.

Comment: I am even not so sure, that this is specific for the [tag:postgres] tag, though I am mentioning PostgreSQL functions here.

Comment: It would probably be better to simply use the record identifier.  My assumption is you need to keep predictability based on the input so the key is easily calculated.  Truncating the md5 to the high bits seems like you'll end up with a lot more key collisions for different strings.  64 bits is quite generous, but not if you are only using a fraction of that address space.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch _"the record identifier"_ We don't keep oid's with our tables unfortunately. We need to create contexts from the determined key-fields.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch Not to mention that the record oid isn't unique regarding of all tables in a database and schema.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch _"Truncating the md5 to the high bits seems like you'll end up with a lot more key collisions for different strings."_ Sure, the probability for collisions increases. The question is if there's a better way than simple truncation of the 128 bit value to make collisions more unlikely.

Comment: I ran into a problem like that designing a concurrent hashmap, where the bucketing algorithm was too naive.. truncation of a uniformly distributed algorithm does not always result in a uniformly distributed result.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch I've updated my question a bit giving more background information. I'd appreciate your input in the form of an answer.

Comment: Why aren't you just using a SELECT FOR UPDATE? Also, postgres do hold an update lock on rows that had been updated, this lock is released when the transaction finishes.

Comment: @LieRyan That doesn't help for the specific problem we have to solve. I need a function to test if record is locked to show that state in the GUI.

Comment: You can use SELECT FOR UPDATE NOWAIT or SELECT FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED to check if a row is being locked by another transaction.

Comment: @LieRyan The row is selected via a Delphi Table component and it's not so easy to change these behaviors. I am aware of all these variants how to select rows in SQL. It's too complicated to explain all that here. My question is how to get a fairly good 64 bit hash, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

That's a good approach.

```
SELECT pg_advisory_xact_lock(
  ('x' || md5(input_text))::bit(64)::bigint
);
```

(Whether you use a transaction or session-level lock depends on how it's invoked.)

It's unfortunate that PostgreSQL lacks a better hexadecimal or byte conversion to bigint, but performance-wise, the overall calculation is extremely fast and will not be the bottleneck.

---

P.S. While I think your solution is best for your situation, an alternative approach is

```
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE lock (
  key text PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE FUNCTION lock_delete() RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
  BEGIN
    DELETE FROM lock;
    RETURN NULL;
  END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER delete AFTER INSERT ON lock
FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE lock_delete();
```

Then you can `INSERT INTO lock VALUES (text_input)`. Records are deleted, but maintain a lock for the duration of the transaction.

This is slower than an advisory lock and imposes vacuum load, but avoids hash conflicts and does not limit the number of locks.